# Magento 1.14 vs 2.0 Enterprise edition

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-1.14, magento2-migration-tool

Looking at the features of the Enterprise edition for Magento `1.14` and `2.0`, I am wondering which version to opt for ?

Some of `Magento 2 EE` highlights is:

1. Database scalability
2. Advanced search (Solr -
   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/solr/solr-overview.html)
3. Job queue opportunities Message Queues
   (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/mq/rabbitmq-overview.html)
4. Google Tag Manager support
5. Extended admin rights management features
6. The ability to manage customer attributes and create custom customer
   attributes Scheduled FTP/SFTP transfer via XML
7. Dedicated 24/7 support

Magento Enterprise Edition `1.14.2` includes the latest versions of the `Zend 1 Framework and Redis integration`, as well as refinements to full-page caching that enable more pages to be served from cache. The release also includes many quality enhancements.

- What are the key differences between Magento `2.0 vs 1.14` Enterprise
  Edition ?
- What should be suggested to a client where existing website is built
  in 1.14 with respect to 2.0 enterprise ?

P.S Do not close it. If you think its too broad, at least try to answer key highlights

Answer (score 2):

IMHO if your client already have an Enterprise 1.14.X you should evaluate:

- How Many Customs / Modules your store have and how many time(money) you need to migrate such functionalities to M2
- How much time you need to Re-Implement the store Theme (Believe me it's not trivial at all)
- How important would be RabbitMQ Support or Database Split for your store operation (These are the only two difference I found in EE) Both Support SOLR but M2 support newest version, anyway... will be moved to Elastic Search in the next release.

Basically is a matter of Money if your client can spend a lot of money for a few new features... you may be interested in a M2 implementation. Otherwise you can wait a few months for some new features / improvements.

My advice right now is:

If you just have some 3rd party extensions that are already migrated to M2 and can afford the theme migration GO to M2! otherwise keep in M1 (Magento will be supporting 1.X until Dic 2018).

Comment: Is Mage going to stop supporting 1.X for both CE and EE ?

Comment: Yes, 3 years from Magento2 official release (dic 2015)

Comment: Here's more info about [split databases](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html). Magento 1.x had nothing like it.

Comment: Yes I told you about (without details) but is a point to take in mind to evaluate